# Creating a dictionary from a using a list and dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a list that is created using two columns of a dataframe. I need to create a dictionary where keys will be the elements of the list and the values will be the elements of a column in the dataframe. Below is an Example that I just created. The dataframe I am using is large and so is the list.

```
data={'init':[1,2,1], 'term':[2,3,3], 'cost':[10,20,30]}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
link=[(1,2),(1,3),(2,3) ]
```

I need to create the following dictionary using the dataframe and list.

```
link_cost={(1,2): 10,(1,3):30,(2,3):20,}
```

Could anyone help me with this? Any comments or instruction would be appreciated.

Comment: `dict(zip(link, df["cost"]))`?

Comment: cost is the dataframe is the cost of each link connecting init node and term node.

Comment: @mars That should be clearly explained in the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) then [`Series.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
d = df.set_index(['init', 'term'])['cost'].reindex(index=link).to_dict()
```

`d`:

```
{(1, 2): 10, (1, 3): 30, (2, 3): 20}
```

[`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with multiple columns will create a MultiIndex which can be indexed with tuples. Selecting a specific column and then [`reindexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) will allow the list `link` to reorder/select specific values from the Series. [`Series.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html) will create the dictionary output.

---

Setup used:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'init': [1, 2, 1], 
    'term': [2, 3, 3],
    'cost': [10, 20, 30]
})
link = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you even using pandas for this? You have the `dict` right there:

```
link_cost = dict(zip(link, data['cost']}}
# or if you must use the dataframe it's the same
link_cost = dict(zip(link, df['cost']}}
```

---

```
{(1,2): 10, (2,3):20, (1,3):30}
```

Comment: I just created that example. The data frame I am using is large. I edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use [`DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), [`Index.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) and [`DataFrame.itertuples`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'init': [1, 2, 1], 'term': [2, 3, 3], 'cost': [10, 20, 30]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
link = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 3)]

cols = ["init", "term"]
new = df.set_index(cols)
res = dict(new[new.index.isin(link)].itertuples(name=None))
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
{(1, 2): 10, (2, 3): 20, (1, 3): 30}
```